# Return dict with key values only if values have duplicates in it

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-template

I am trying to iterate over the dict and validate against the below condition but

```
"{{ list1 | difference(list1|unique) }}"
```

Is giving empty list only eventhough the list has duplicates in it.

I have the input like this

```
dict1 = {'a':[1,2,3],'b':[2,2,3],'c':[3,4],'d':[1,2,1]}
```

Trying to get lists having duplicates and get the output like this

```
dict2 = {'b':[2,2,3],'d':[1,2,1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried myself and got the required output with the below code

```
- set_fact:
    dict2: "{{ dict2|d({})|combine({item.key: item.value}) }}"
  with_dict: "{{ dict1 }}"
  vars:
    count1: "{{ item.value | unique | count }}"
    count2: "{{ item.value | count }}"
  when: count1!=count2
- debug: var=dict2
```

Thanks, any suggestions are welcome